# If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta$ are ordinals, then $\alpha_1<\alpha_2\iff \beta+\alpha_1<\beta+\alpha_2$

Tags: proof-explanation, ordinals

In my textbook, there is a theorem along with its proof as follows:

---

> If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta$ are ordinals, then $\alpha_1<\alpha_2\iff \beta+\alpha_1<\beta+\alpha_2$.

---

**Proof:**

1. $\alpha_1<\alpha_2\implies \beta+\alpha_1<\beta+\alpha_2$

We prove this statement by induction on $\alpha_2$. Assume that $\forall \gamma<\alpha_2:\alpha_1<\gamma\implies\beta+\alpha_1<$ $\beta+\gamma$.

- If $\alpha_2=\delta+1$, then $\alpha_1\le\delta$. By IH, we obtain $\beta+\alpha_1\le\beta+\delta<(\beta+\delta)+1=$ $\beta+(\delta+1)=\beta+\alpha_2$.
- If $\alpha_2$ is a limit ordinal, then $\alpha_1+1<\alpha_2$ and $\beta+\alpha_1<(\beta+\alpha_1)+1=\beta+(\alpha_1+1)$ $\le \sup\{\beta+\delta\mid\delta<\alpha_2\}=\beta+\alpha_2$. Thus $\beta+\alpha_1<\beta+\alpha_2$.

2. $\beta+\alpha_1<\beta+\alpha_2\implies \alpha_1<\alpha_2$

- If $\alpha_2<\alpha_1$, then $\beta+\alpha_2<\beta+\alpha_1$, which is a contradiction.
- If $\alpha_2=\alpha_1$, then $\beta+\alpha_2=\beta+\alpha_1$, which is a contradiction.

Thus $\alpha_2>\alpha_1$

---

**My problem:**

I'm able to understand almost the whole proof, except for one point:

> $\beta+(\alpha_1+1)\le \sup\{\beta+\delta\mid\delta<\alpha_2\}$

- First, i don't understand how the authors derive that inequality.
- Second, it seems weird to me that the authors even don't use the Inductive Hypothesis in this part, while the proof is by transfinite induction.

Any elaboration is greatly appreciated!

Comment: By definition, $\beta+\alpha_2=\sup\{\beta+\delta\mid\delta<\alpha_2\}$.  Now the set of $\beta+\delta$ contains $\beta+\alpha_1+1$ so you get the inequality.  The author could have used the successor case to say that $\beta+\alpha_1<\beta+(\alpha_1+1)$, but it isn't really necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much @user10354138! I got your point. By the way, I think you meant *the set $\{\beta+\delta\mid\delta<\alpha_2\}$* rather than *the set $\beta+\delta$*.

Comment: Yes, the set *of* $\beta+\delta$ means $\{\beta+\delta\mid\delta<\alpha_2\}$.